# при использовании RewriteRule не приходит ответ от обработчика

Tags: javascript, php

```
https://example.ru/пример  //запрос страницы
https://example.ru/пример/ //в браузере мы видим ее же (код 200)
https://example.ru/primer/ //по факту загружается эта
```

это делается через RewriteRule в .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^пример/$ /primer/ [E=FINISH:1,L]
RewriteRule ^primer/$ https://example.ru/пример/ [R=301,L]
```

тут все работает

проблема в том, что на странице находится форма, данные которой методом

```
.serialize()
```

отправляются обработчику

```
https://example.ru/primer/obrabotchik.php
```

данные отправляются, но ответа нет, хотя без подмены адресов все работает.
Понятно, что проблема из-за RewriteRule, но вот как ее решить?
Подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен
при обращении к обработчику относительный адрес был заменен на полный
т.е. было./obrabotchik.php
стало https://example.ru/primer/obrabotchik.php